# Loop not waiting for setInterval() inside it before next repeat

Tags: javascript

What i want, is to make loop wait before setInterval() function does its job before next execution of loop again.
But loop do not seem to wait and setInterval() keeps on waiting for its time.

```
<script>
var x=5;
while(x>0)
 {
    console.log("new loop..\n Left:"+x);
    x--;
    demo=3;
    start=setInterval(function(){
        if(demo<=0)
        clearInterval(start);
        else
        {
        demo--;
        console.log("time left for next loop:"+demo);
        }
    },1000);
}
</script>
```

After seeing this now, i know delaying a loop is not possible. But any ideas making what i want happen will be appreciable.

**NO JQUERY PLZ**

Comment: what is your question what you mean stopping a loop is not possible..break and return should stop while loop

Comment: @Carcigenicate, i understand what asynchronous and synchronous means.But i cant really figure out what u mean by 'wkorking with it'.Please clarify a little

Comment: @Carcigenicate, what i actually what to make differs from what i am asking. Answers i will get here will just give me a hint of what method i can use in that application. All i liked in those answers was the jquery one, but i m not comfortable with it right now..i just stick with JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd write a comment but cannot because of low reputation. 
Please re-think your approach completely and consider that setinterval calls the nested function async.
e.g. (not tested, but maybe you get the idea)

```
<script>
var x =6;
function recursive(){
    x--;
    if (x==0){
        return; //end of program
    }
    start=setInterval(function(){
            if(demo<=0)
            {
                clearInterval(start);
                recursive();
            }
            else
            {
            demo--;
            console.log("time left for next loop:"+demo);
            }
        },1000);
}


</script>
```

Comment: the answer didnt help me directly but finally i made what i wanted to with changed concepts in my mind..thnks a lot